# Converting string address to int address

Tags: c#, memory

So i couldn't find anything at google, believe in you guys.

I'm converting address from `string` which I read using `StreamReader`. 
Simply need advice how to convert it to actually be able to use `readprocessmemory`, I want to read address from .txt file.

Address looks like this: `0x003D6ED4` .

just simple int addr for rpm but can't somehow make it working so far.

PS: no, `int.parse` and `convert.toint32` doesnt work.
thanks

Comment: I believe you would need to Marshal the pointer. Not sure on the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you need [HexNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) parsing:

```
var addr = int.Parse("0x003D6ED4".Substring(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

`Substring(2)` - to skip `0x` at the begining

Comment: @code4life oooops, time to feed my bear :) updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also do `int addr = Convert.ToInt32("0x003D6ED4".Substring(2), 16);`